# How to prevent duplicates links from Python code when scraping site for html links

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following python code. However, I am having problem removing duplicate links from my results.

```
search_results_links = []
for i in range(len(search_results)):
                if search_results[i]['href'] == "":
                                continue
                elif (search_results[i]['href'][0] == "/"):
                                search_results_links.append("https://www.census.gov"+search_results[i]['href'])
                elif (search_results[i]['href'][0] == "#") :
                                continue
                elif (search_results[i]['href'][0] == "j") :
                                continue
                else:
                                search_results_links.append(search_results[i]['href'])

# Remove duplicates.
search_results_links.sort()
search_results_links2 = []

for i in range(len(search_results_links)):
                if search_results_links[i][:-1] == search_results_links[i - 1]:
                                continue
                else:
                                search_results_links2.append(search_results_links[i])
```

How should I update this code to only pull unique links?

Comment: What do the lists `search_results_links` and `search_results` contain?

Comment: search_results = soup.find_all("a", href=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a list to store all the links, use a set.

Considering everything else in your code is working fine, you don't need to remove duplicates if you first do a lookup in the set and then append that link to the set. Something like this:

```
search_results_links = set()
for i in range(len(search_results)):
  if search_results[i]['href'] == "":
    continue
  elif (search_results[i]['href'][0] == "/"):
    if "https://www.census.gov"+search_results[i]['href'] not in search_results_links:
      search_results_links.add("https://www.census.gov"+search_results[i]['href'])
  elif (search_results[i]['href'][0] == "#") :
    continue
  elif (search_results[i]['href'][0] == "j") :
    continue
  else:
    if search_results[i]['href'] not in search_results_links:
      search_results_links.add(search_results[i]['href'])
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to have fixed the problem.